# Why can one hide the launcher to the left but not the bar at the top in Unity?

Tags: unity

From [Is there a way to configure Unity's top bar to autohide?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/557107/is-there-a-way-to-configure-unitys-top-bar-to-autohide#557109) I know it is not possible to hide Unity's top bar. From a design perspective my question is why?

I do not understand why one can hide the launcher on the left but not the bar at the top.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is intentionally done by design, the Unity top bar is used for indicators and notifications, which the Ubuntu design team wants to always be visible for quick access of applications and their notifications. You always can press the <kbd>F11</kbd> key when you want to run the currently used application in full screen mode without any launcher bar or top bar being visible at all, but this is something that most operating systems are having in common, and I think that the Unity top bar doesn't take away too much space. One other example is the GNOME desktop environment - the top bar there is always visible as well, this also made by design from the GNOME designers team.

Update : In the GNOME 3 desktop environment it is possible to circumvent the default design by installing the **external `hide-top-bar` extension** as pointed out by @Mark Kirby in his comment.

Comment: One of those indicators is the indicator menubar.

Comment: One could use the same quick access argument for the launcher but the launcher can be set to hidden.

Comment: "One other example is the GNOME desktop environment - the top bar there is always visible as well." Not true, a simple extension can hide it https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/545/hide-top-bar/