# Ubuntu 16.04 hide top panel/bar

Tags: unity, panel, autohide

How to remove/hide the entire top panel?

I searched for it but could not find a solution. This thing is really driving my nuts. I could not even imagine that it would be so difficult.

[image]

Answers from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/557107/is-there-a-way-to-configure-unitys-top-bar-to-autohide) topic didn't help me.

This is not what I want.

`wmctrl -r ":ACTIVE:" -b toggle,fullscreen`

CompizConfig doesn't help too. it leaves top panel half transparent anyway.

`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

Also can't install HideTopBar gnome extension.

[image]

Comment: It's not possible, here's the reason: https://askubuntu.com/questions/115672/why-cant-the-unity-panel-be-hidden

Comment: It's a pity. What Linux distro would you advise in order to hide all system elements from desktop screen?

Comment: @mr.boris: We don't recommend other Linux distributions than Ubuntu on Ask *Ubuntu*. However you may want to try some of the other officially supported desktop environments in Ubuntu: GNOME Shell, MATE, KDE, Xfce and LXDE.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Is it possible to solve this task on Ubuntu using **GNOME Shell** or **MATE** or **KDE** or **Xfce** or **LXDE**? I'm just tired of trying... I want to know exactly.

Comment: @mr.boris It is possible to autohide top/bottom panel in Ubuntu MATE and Kubuntu. Probably can be done in GNOME shell too with the "Hide Top Bar" extension. Don't know about Xfce or LXDE.

Comment: @mr.boris:  The Xfce4 desktop has a configurable panel or none, if you so want.

Comment: @pomsky Than you, I tried to install "Hide Top Bar" extension for GNOME shell but I have a problem with GNOME shell integration with the browser, so I can't install any extensions for it now.

Comment: @WillemK Than you, I'll try Xfce. I hope it will work.

Comment: @mr.boris You can always manually install extensions by using Tweak Tool or extracting the extension folder to `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and then activate the extension using Tweak Tool.